# How to get the toggle back to an option group button after defining terms for a table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, togglebutton

I have a option group of toggle buttons called **opButtons**. Since the buttons register as number to the table, I used **Select Case** to define what they should actually be recorded as in the table. This Select Case was attached to a hidden text box on the form "**optext**." This code works to change the number to what I need in the table but now the buttons won't keep their toggle position, they just instantly refresh as if they have never been pushed.
Is there a way where I can have them keep their toggle position?
Below is the code for the table:

```
    Private Sub opButtons_Click()
Select Case Me![opButtons]
    Case 1
        Me![optext] = "L1"
    Case 2
        Me![optext] = "L2"
    Case 3
        Me![optext] = "L3"
    Case 4
        Me![optext] = "R1"
    Case 5
        Me![optext] = "R2"
    Case 6
        Me![optext] = "R3"
    Case 7
        Me![optext] = "None"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the option group is unbound, it will only change from code or manually by the user. So, I guess, it is either bound to some field, or you have code running that "resets" it.

Answer (score 0):

@Gustav Thanks you got me thinking about what might be resetting it. I had the control source for both the Option Group and the hidden text box, as the same column on the table. I took the control source away from the Option Group, since this just sends what I want to the textbox, but the text box writes to the table. Now this works. The toggle buttons work and the code works to change the toggle button default values to text in the table. Thanks for the insight!